# Android Studio with Gradle incompatibility (Google Play Services issue)

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin

I am developing an android app with Android Studio 0.8.9. I am using Gradle to build my project.

I want to include `google-play-services.jar` file into my project in order to use push notification api.

I have added those statements into my gradle (application layer) file as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley_23042014.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
}
```

but it never works. I get the following error:

```
Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
```

I've checked bunch of websites (including Stackoverflow.com). None of them has worked for me.

I have latest versions of `Google Support Library`, `Google Support Repository`, `Google Play Services`.

Here is my libs directory

[image: lbs directory]

My SDK version like:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
```

What I have done wrong? If anyone has any idea please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're including Play Services via:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
```

you don't need this:

```
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
```

so just remove it.

Since the first line of your dependencies will make it automatically pick up any jar files you put in your libs directory:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

make sure you remove the jars from there as well.
For that matter, there are other libraries you shouldn't include via specific jars.

Instead of this:

```
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.2.3.jar')
```

use this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.3
```

(Note that later versions of GSON are available).

Comment: It does not work. I had also tried that before. I get the same error.

Comment: It still does not work. But the error changed as 'Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/AccessibilityService/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;'

Comment: See that v4-support library in your libs folder? Remove it, like I said.

Comment: I got it know. You mean removing jar files physically. Now it works, thanks.